# Pyspark group data by year range

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the pyspark dataframe like the following

```
>>> df.show()
+----+---+---+-----+
|Year|Sex|NOC|count|
+----+---+---+-----+
|1924|  M|BUL|   31|
|1948|  M|EGY|  166|
|1980|  F|POL|  127|
|1984|  M|SYR|    9|
|1992|  F|NGR|   30|
|1992|  M|PER|   15|
|1996|  M|BUL|  128|
|1976|  M|ISL|   26|
|2004|  F|GRN|    2|
|2012|  M|SVK|   35|
|2002|  F|SLO|   41|
|2008|  F|SLO|   27|
|2008|  M|HKG|   22|
|2012|  M|MLT|    3|
|2000|  F|SEN|   23|
|1964|  M|GRE|   26|
|2006|  M|ESP|   12|
|2008|  M|MON|    4|
|2002|  M|DEN|    5|
|1964|  F|ISL|    1|
+----+---+---+-----+
```

I want a new dataframe such that the years are grouped into ranges and count column is summed on the year's range. For example the expected resulting output will be:

```
Year  Sex  NOC  count
1921-1940  M  BUL 153
1921-1940  F  BUL 132
1941-1960  M  BUL 984
1941-1960  F  BUL 112
....
2001-2016  M  GER  651
2001-2016  F  GER  322
```

Currently I am using the following approach but not working

```
res = df.withColumn("range", df.Year - (df.Year % interval)).groupBy("range").agg(df_mf_prop.count())
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!